# Check to see if a file exists before writing to it and then ask to overwrite in C with POSIX

Tags: c, file-io, error-handling, posix

Ok, I have a homework assignment to write a file in C using the POSIX API that asks for a filename to read from, a filename to write to and then copies one to the other. I have done this and it works great! I am trying to put some error checking in and I want to check to see if the file to be written to already exists and if it does, then ask if the user wishes to overwrite. The problem is that it always states that the file exists, even if it does not. The  rest of the program works just fine. I have read a lot on here and found a lot of useful stuff on POSIX, but can't find this type of problem to reference. Below is my code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>   // POSIX: give access to open
#include <unistd.h>  // POSIX: gives access to read, write, close
#include <stdio.h>   // POSIX: gives access to BUFSIZ

int main() {

int source = -1;
int target;
char sourcefile[50];
char targetfile[50];
char buff[BUFSIZ];
char ow[3];
size_t size;

printf("Please enter the name of the file you wish to read: ");
scanf( "%s", sourcefile );
printf( "\n" );
printf("Please enter the name of the file you wish to write to: ");
scanf( "%s", targetfile );
printf( "\n" );

source = open( sourcefile, O_RDONLY, 0);
//Test for existence of input file
if( source == -1 )
{
    perror( "Cannot find file" );
    return 1;
}
target = open( targetfile, O_WRONLY, 0644 );
//Test for existence of output file
if( target == 0 )
{
    perror( "File already exists" );
    printf( "Do you wish to overwrite? (yes or no): " );
    scanf( "%s", ow );

    if( strcmp( ow, "yes" ) == 0 )
    {
        target = open( targetfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);   
    }else
    {
        printf( "Program Terminated!\n" );
        return 1;   
    }   
}else if( target == -1 )
{
    target = open( targetfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
}

while ((size = read(source, buff, BUFSIZ)) > 0) 
{
    write(target, buff, size);
}

close(source);
close(target);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the posted code, target is not assigned to before the first check.  Is this a copy/paste error, or is that the problem you are having?  If so, turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Improving your indentation will help you (and others) read your code.

Comment: My indentation looks great in the actual code, I didn't realize I needed to go back line by line in this to get it to indent properly.

Comment: William, I believe that was my problem, I kinda feel like an idiot now. I will fix that when I get out of class and see if that does it.

Comment: For posting code to SO, indent with 4 spaces per level (no tabs, and make sure that what you copy'n'paste doesn't have tabs in it) and then use the **`{}`** symbol above the edit box to indent all the code by another 4 spaces so it appears as code.

Comment: I believe I have fixed the problem with indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `open(2)` with `O_EXCL` to create the purported new file. This will *fail* if the file already exists; in that case abort fatally. Otherwise you can write the desired file contents into it.

If you want to be atomic, you can write the file contents into a temporary file (using `tmpfile`) and then atomically replace the created file with `rename(2)`. That way the new file is either empty or a complete copy.

---

An alternative (suggested by @R.) is to not bother opening the target file, copying into a temporary file, and then using `link(2)` instead of `rename` to attempt to put the new file in its destination location. This will fail if the destination already exists. This may have the (arguable) benefit that if someone else creates the target file in the meantime and *doesn't* use the same care that we do, then you would be a bit more gentle in that case. (But if someone else wants stampedes around your filesystem without care, there's only so much you can do.)

Comment: For atomic replacement, I would use `link`, rather than `rename`, since it will fail if the target exists. You can then prompt the user whether to replace, and if so, use `rename`.

Comment: @R..: OK, but I had assumed we already used `open` to make sure the new file didn't already exist. `link` looks like a good idea if we skip that initial step. Note that `rename` *is* atomic, it just doesn't care whether the target exists. (I guess a file existing doesn't prevent someone else from *overwriting* it.)